# Vue JS axios request with filter - this.XX.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, api, vue.js, axios

I am having issues implementing a simple search function on a JSON file I get through an API.

The individual elements work: I am able to receive the API data, I am able to perform search on non-API data and also on API data from certain APIs.

The big issue is that even without filtering, the data does not get displayed and the error I am getting in the console states that

***this.items.filter is not a function***

Thanks a lot!

```html
<input type="text" v-model="search">
<div v-for="content in filteredItems" :key="content.name">
  <span> {{ content }}</span>
</div>
```

```js
export default {
  name: "hello",
  data: () => ({
    search: '',
    items: []
  }),

mounted() {
  var self = this;
  axios
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      self.items = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
computed: {
  filteredItems: function() {
    let searchTerm = (this.search || "").toLowerCase();
    return this.items.filter(function(item) {
      let title = (item.title || "").toLowerCase();
      return title.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
    });
  }
}
```

If I change the API to this one, for instance, the search works. 
https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` returns a single item.

It's not in an array. It's an object. There is no `filter`.

`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all` returns an array. There is a `filter`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! Is there a way to use a filter on a single item?

Comment: @Matthias ... put it into an array?

Comment: thanks for all the quick replies. I'm quite new to JS and Vue. Do I convert it in the computed section? 
 Any resource where I could look it up? 5mins google didn't really solve it.

Comment: `self.items = [response.data]` is sufficient, but if you're trying to handle multiple endpoints that may or may not return an array you might want to check the type and handle it there. With the caveat that different APIs will return different things, so you'd need to handle a single object, an array, an object keys by, say, IDs as keys and data as the keys' properties, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking your time and providing this high quality input! Really appreciated!